# yum Damaged repomd.xml file

Tags: fedora, yum

I'm having trouble doing anything with yum on Fedora 16. Here is the output I'm getting:

```
[user@mycomputer yum-3.4.3]$ sudo yum update
[sudo] password for user: 
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, priorities, refresh-packagekit
adobe-linux-x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |   39 B     00:00 ... 
http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml for adobe-linux-x86_64: Damaged repomd.xml file
Trying other mirror.
fedora                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |   39 B     00:00 ... 
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/16/Everything/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml for fedora: Damaged repomd.xml file
Trying other mirror.
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. Protocol mismatch./
removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/16/rpmfusion-free/mirrorlist.txt
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. Protocol mismatch./
removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/16/rpmfusion-free-updates/mirrorlist.txt
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. Protocol mismatch./
removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/16/rpmfusion-nonfree/mirrorlist.txt
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. Protocol mismatch./
removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/16/rpmfusion-nonfree-updates/mirrorlist.txt
updates                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |   39 B     00:00 ... 
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/16/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml for updates: Damaged repomd.xml file
Trying other mirror.
adobe-linux-x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |   39 B     00:00 ... 
http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml for adobe-linux-x86_64: Damaged repomd.xml file
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from adobe-linux-x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try
```

And here are the contents of my /etc/yum.conf:

```
[user@mycomputer yum-3.4.3]$ cat /etc/yum.conf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[main]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
keepcache=0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
debuglevel=2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
logfile=/var/log/yum.log                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
exactarch=1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
obsoletes=1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
gpgcheck=1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
plugins=1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
installonly_limit=3                                                                                                                                             
proxy=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
PROXY_USERNAME=user
PROXY_PASSWORD=password
```

And here are the contents of /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo:

```
[user@mycomputer yum-3.4.3]$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo 
[fedora]
name=Fedora $releasever - $basearch
failovermethod=priority
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/os/
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$basearch

[fedora-debuginfo]
name=Fedora $releasever - $basearch - Debug
failovermethod=priority
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/debug/
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-debug-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=0
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$basearch

[fedora-source]
name=Fedora $releasever - Source
failovermethod=priority
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/source/SRPMS/
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-source-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=0
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$basearch
```

Does anyone have any ideas for how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a damage of your `repomd.xml` (repository meta data). I see here two possible problems:

- your proxy server has a stale partially retrieved copy or just
  refuses to give a good one.
- The bad copy was put onto the repository master server and then all
  mirrors pull it (I used to see it). Anyway at time I write the response the first picked
  mirror returned a valid file.

Your `fedora.repo` file is fine.

Comment: Ah, ok. I did just change the proxy - could that have something to do with it? The IP, username, and password are all correct, and I can ssh into it. Is there a way I could get yum to use a SOCKS connection?

Comment: wait, wait. sorry. I am still looking at the output

Comment: could you please, try this command at this system's shell prompt: `wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/16/Everything/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml`

Comment: Alright, got the file repomd.xml. Here are the contents:

Comment: [user@mycomputer yum-3.4.3]$ cat repomd.xml 
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.0
Protocol mismatch.

Comment: Should I put this somewhere?

Comment: Ah, right. Now I have it. Should I replace the other repomd files with it?

Comment: The file is 4311 bytes long presently. it is a text file with this content at the beginning: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<repomd xmlns="http://linux.duke.edu/metadata/repo"

Comment: No, you should make yum to be able to connect to the internet.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working by adding a proxy tag in my `yum.conf` file which was initially missing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the yum.conf

   ```
   vi /etc/yum.conf
   ```
2. Add "proxy" tag in last

   ```
   proxy=http://XXXX.XXX.XXXX.XXX:XXXX
   ```

save and close. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

VLC is not pre-installed repository on Fedora 20-23.

If you installed their release repository in your computer, try to delete it and test download again. After you installing the vlc applications, just delete the uncompleted repository.

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
ls -lrt
rm -f rpmfusion-free*
```

Everything will be all right after you delete that unOfficial fusion repository.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
# sudo yum clean all
# sudo yum update
```