# Fedora 16 'yum update' not working

Tags: fedora, yum

I have recently installed Fedora 16 on my desktop. After the intallastion was over I tried to update my repos by issuing `sudo yum update` command. I got the following output: 
`Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: fedora. Please verify its path and try again`

I Searched on the Internet for the similar problem. There were quite a few solutions available and I tried all. I tried the following things:

1. Edit `fedora.repo` and `fedora-update.repo` in which I removed `s` from `https`.
2. I tried updating certificate using `yum update ca-certificates` and `yum reinstall ca-certificates`
3. I tried `yum clean all` and `rpm --rebuilddb`.
4. I also commented `mirrorlist` line and uncommented `baseurl` line in `fedora.repo` and `fedora-update.repo` files.

None of the above solutions are working for me. Can anyone suggest where the problem lies?

Following are the links where I took reference from:

1. [yum Damaged repomd.xml file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49618/yum-damaged-repomd-xml-file)
2. http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-263369.html
3. http://digitizor.com/2009/06/17/how-to-fix-the-cannot-retrieve-repository-metadata-repomd-xml-error-in-fedora-11/

Answer (score 2):

Fedora 16 was [end of life on 2013-02-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fedora_releases#Version_history), almost 2 years ago. The repositories, for that version, probably have been taken offline.

You should reinstall a supported version.

Comment: suppported version of what? repository or operating system as a whole?

Comment: Of Fedora. If you following the link you see that Fedora 19 will end-of-life in a few days, so take 20 or 21